# Does epoll(), do its job in O(1)?

Tags: linux, network-programming, epoll

Wikipedia says

> unlike the older system calls, which
>   operate at O(n), epoll operates in
>   O(1) [2]).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoll

However, the source code at fs/eventpoll.c on Linux-2.6.38,
seems it is implemented with an RB tree for searching, which has O(logN)

```
/*
 * Search the file inside the eventpoll tree. The RB tree operations
 * are protected by the "mtx" mutex, and ep_find() must be called with
 * "mtx" held.
 */
static struct epitem *ep_find(struct eventpoll *ep, struct file *file, int fd)
{
```

In fact, I couldn't see any man page saying the complexity of epoll() is O(1).
Why is it known as O(1)?

Comment: I would vote this up because you really did your homework, but I'm maxed out on daily votes :P

Comment: @ddoman: What Keoki Zee meant was that you did prior research on your own before asking this question. A lot of new (and old!) users of Stack Overflow can't even be bothered to do that.

Comment: Research, for doing research :)

Comment: Well, google seems to [agree](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22epoll+operates+in+O%281%29%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#sclient=psy&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=RCb&rls=org.mozilla:en-US%3Aofficial&source=hp&q=%22epoll+operates+in+O%281%29%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=27b93cf21cbb40b9&biw=1339&bih=795)

Comment: There's no way `epoll` executes in `O(1)`, as the number of file descriptors it needs to watch isn't constant. There has to be some kind of repetition construct.

Comment: Would someone explain this `epoll()` function people keep talking about?  I can't find any function with that name.  `epoll` is a whole family of functions, not all of which have the same complexity.

Comment: @Insilico, you're making the assumption that `epoll()` must _scan_ the file descriptors to find ready ones. `epoll()` can also _wait_ on the descriptors to become ready...

Comment: @sarnold: I made no assumption that `epoll` is scanning anything. What I meant was that if you're waiting on events that can happen at anytime then `O(1)` operation is not guaranteed by definition. Either that or everyone talking about the `epoll` API meant something else by `O(1)`.

Comment: @Insilico, hehe, good point. `O(asleep)`. :)

Comment: It is somewhat inaccurate to say that `epoll` operates at O(1). `epoll` operates at O(log(n)) in respect to _adding and removing descriptors_, at O(n) in respect of _ready descriptors_, and at O(1) in respect of _monitored descriptors_ -- which is the whole point of `epoll`. Adding/removing descriptors is a rare thing, waiting for readiness is frequent, and you usually have _many more_ descriptors in your set than are actually ready. Insofar, while `epoll` does not really operate at O(1), it does so where it matters. The common case is fast, the uncommon case is not.

Comment: What does n in `O(n) for ready descriptors` signify? I thought it would be different from the input set. O(m) where m is the number of ready events.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This makes sense once you look for `ep_find`. I only spent a few minutes with it and I see `ep_find` is only called by `epoll_ctl`.

So indeed, when you add the descriptors (`EPOLL_CTL_ADD`) that costly operation is performed. BUT when doing **the real work** (`epoll_wait`) it isn't. You only add the descriptors in the beginning.

In conclusion, it's not enough to ask the complexity of `epoll`, since there is no `epoll` system call. You want the individual complexities of `epoll_ctl`, `epoll_wait` etc.

#### Other stuff

There are other reasons to avoid `select` and use `epoll`. When using select, you don't know how many descriptors need attention. So you must keep track of the biggest and loop to it.

```
rc = select(...);
/* check rc */
for (s = 0; s <= maxfd; s++) {
    if (FD_ISSET(s)) {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Now with `epoll` it's a lot cleaner:

```
nfds = epoll_wait(epollfd, events, MAX_EVENTS, -1);
/* check nfds */
for (n = 0; n < nfds; ++n) {
    /* events[n].data.fd needs attention */
}
```

Comment: select returns the number of ready fd's too, in the worst case you need to loop through them all though (if `maxfd` has an event).

Comment: @nos And how would you use that number to replace the loop ?

Comment: Somewhere you need to have a list of all your file descripors. I often use a linked list if I'm using select.  `int handled = 0; while(client) { if(FD_ISSET(client->fd,read_set) {handle(client); handled++; } if(handled == rc) break; client = clients->next;}` , no need to check from `0 to rc`, only check the FDs you actually are monitoring, and no need to check more fds when you handled all the events select reported.

Comment: Yes, you're right, you can *shorten* the loop. But, as you correctly pointed in your comment, you still have to process all your list (in the unfortunate case a descriptor near "the end" needs attention). And if that list is large and the descriptors are the first and the last..

Answer (score 1):

I think epoll wait is O(1) with epollet if you ask for 1 event.
And upd and add could be amortized O(1) if they used a descent hashtbl implementation.

This needs checking and man pages should mention complexity!